# Trying to use Django, do I need to install Apache manually if Wamp already did

Tags: python, django, apache, wamp, mod-wsgi

To make my question clear:

1. I have had wamp installed, and it brought Apache. Will this Apache be used by others like Django?
2. If the wamp Apache is enough for others, its Apache is in wamp directory C:\wamp\bin\apache, not sth like C:\programs file...It is ok for django
3. If I have to install Apache manually for django, will the step be install Apache, install mod_wsgi?

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strictly interpreted, Django doesn't "use" Apache. Apache is just one way to direct requests (via mod_wsgi, for example) to your django app and returns the result to the user.

The existing Apache install will be fine. It doesn't matter where it is as long as it's running and reachable.

You will need to install mod_wsgi and configure it so that it knows about your Django app.

You can find documentation for configuring Apache and mod_wsgi here:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/

Comment: Thank you for clearing this for me! So once I get the mod_wsgi.co, I can just place it under C:\wamp\bin\apache\Apache2.4.4\modules?

Comment: Yes, I believe so. I haven't configured Apache in a while, though. You should be able to find a fair amount of resources for installing mod_wsgi, though.

Comment: Thank you so much. I got Apache ready, though when it comes to compile mod_wsgi from source code using VS command line, I got:  mod_wsgi.c(34) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'httpd.h': No such file or directory. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need Apache *at all* at this point. For development, things work much better if you use the built in development server, as described in the tutorial.

Comment: Thank you, just in case it will be needed someday:)